# Pathfinder Cavalier looking to make an all rounder build

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization

Hey I'm going into a Pathfinder Society game soon and I was wondering if this setup would be any good.  The goal is to be a tank/damage dealer both on and off a mount. My Cavalier is Order of Cockatrice.  In this situation, I mean tank as in the ability to not be hit often via a high AC and the HP to take the damage if I do get hit.

Current stats are:

- STR:17
- CON:14
- DEX:14
- INT:10
- WIS:10
- CHA:13

AC:17

Traits: Beast Bond and Armor Expert

Skills: ride, handle animal, bluff, diplomacy (looking to put a rank in ride and dipomacy every level)

I am aiming to be a beast rider from level 7 onwards. Currently a human and feats are power attack, mounted combat and paired opportunists.

Fundamentally I'm looking for advice on how to make the character better at tanking in the short term without losing too much damage.  If possible of course, I've planned to get a Snapping Turtle at level 7 using beast master, to this end **I would like advice on being a tank both on and off my mount**.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. We do things a little differently here; see [About]. This is a Q&A site, *not* a discussion forum, so throwing ideas how there, hashing out concepts, etc, isn't really what we do. We are *happy* to offer build advice, but you need a *really* detailed question, very specific about what you're looking for. Describe the character, the sorts of things you'd like to be capable of accomplishing, the background he'd have, and so on. We need enough information so that we can try to give a One Correct Answer. Or, when you have 20 reputation, you could ask on [Chat].

Comment: Cleaned up the question to focus on the topic, minus the chatty bits, and bold emphasis on what you're trying to have answered.  This should help.